# CommandBar Control onAction get source control

Tags: vba, ms-access

Something that may be simple, but I cant find it in documentations:

This is the part of code that creates a CommandBarControl that fires a function

```
Set CBarControl = cmbRightClick.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
CBarControl.caption = "Open Pat"
CBarControl.Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
CBarControl.FaceId = 59
CBarControl.OnAction = "=SCOpenPat()"
```

Now I want to know which control fired this action. So when I assign this shortcut menu to a Edit, then I want SCOpenPat() to know the edit, its form, and its value.

I also tried to find out if Application.CommandBars.ActionControl somewhere has this information, but no success....

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, found it out my self now.

```
CBarControl.OnAction = "=SCSelectTum([ID])"
```

This actually gives me the ID of the selected Recordset (continous form) which is sufficient for all I want to do.